# "Incorrect Syntax In Sql DataTable. Why?"

Tags: asp.net

```
  public DataTable method(string value)
        {
            sq.Close();
            sq.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter SA = new SqlDataAdapter("select Name,ID from Category where SubOff=" + value, sq);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SA.Fill(DS); // error found at this line
            dt = DS.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
```

I am having an error termed as Incorrect syntax near '='.
This code runs fine yesterday, but its pointing an error today.
Please help me out!

Comment: Always use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation . Otherwise your open for sql injection. What is the value  of `value`? Use the debugger.

Comment: As Tim said, use parameters. Also, if `value` is an empty string, that would cause that error

Comment: value is from another method..

Comment: protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
                string var = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                method(var);
                DataTable dt = method(var);
                DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Name";
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ID";
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
                sq.Close();
        
            
        }
Here it is ..